# Does MCMC Gibbs sampling algorithm first build a steady Markov Chain, then does the sampling to build the posterior distribution?

Tags: bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian, gibbs

I am currently studying MCMC Gibbs sampling and while reading this part, a question has come into my head if MCMC Gibbs sampling first build a steady Markov Chain and does the sampling or does sampling first and while sampling, it builds a steady Markov Chain.

What is its way to sample to build the posterior probability distribution?

Comment: Hi: The markov chain is built by sampling. The thing is, at the beginning, when the sampling starts, the constructed chain hasn't converged to the stationary distribution yet so those samples contribute to the steady state but it's not there when it first starts. I'm not sure if that answers your question but if you keep in mind that sampling is what constitutes the chain itself then I think you'll get it.

Comment: So, it is gradually getting to the steady Markov Chain with the ergodic property all the way from the initial value?

Comment: exactly. the first part before it gets there is called "burn in" and you don't want to count those samples in the summary statistics.

Comment: But what wonders me is that how possibly would I know how long the burn in state should be?

Comment: Hi: there are rules of thumb but generally people use graphics. when the plots of the summary statistics become stable visually, this is an indication of convergence. Do you use R ?  If so, I haven't done MCMC in R in a long time but coda was the R package at the time that did such a thing. It's been close to 10 years so I bet there are updates and other packages that have been developed since. coda was fine though for me. If you don't use R, I can't be of help but my point about graphics still stands.